# Matrix inequality, now what?

Tags: matrices, reference-request

I am looking for some motivations. 
I am reading a book about matrix inequality. e.g. Courant–Fischer equality,  eigenvalue of sum of two matrix, ...

My question is, so what kind of problems I should look for that can help my try to apply the knowledge on matrix inequality and help me better improve my skills ?   Or what to read next ?

Thanks a lot for any suggestions !